# How to find intersected line is from left or right on another line?

Tags: geotools, linestring

There is a main LineString and its direction is known. I want to find the side of intersected lines to this main line.

Example image:

[image: lines]

Black line is main LineString and red one is intersected LineString.

How to find it is on left side?

Any math solutions, recommendations or code examples can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's on both sides.  I suppose you want the one the majority of the distance is on.

Assuming only a single point of intersection, you'd first need to split the line at the intersection and take the length of both sides.

Once you know which side is longer, take any point on that side.

Next, you need to determine what segment of the main line the intersection is on.  Determine the slope of the segment.  If that slope is x, y, the perpendicular to the left is -y, x, that to the right is x, -y.  Knowing that it should be pretty easy to look at the slope of the line from the first point of the main segment to the test point and determine which side it's on.

YOUR EXAMPLE:

Slope from 2,4 to 8,2 is 6,-2.

So the left perpendicular, -y, x is 2, 6 meaning that y increases to the left.

On further thought, it's easier at that point just to compute the point on your segment with the same X as the test point.

Normalize the slope by dividing both values by the length of the segment.  We'll call the normalized slope sx, sy.

Call the difference from the test x to segment start x dx. (dx / sx) * sy gives us the y on our segment at dx.  If the test Y is greater than that, it's to the left, otherwise right.

This test doesn't work for a vertical line but that's an easy case to solve.  It's to the left if segment y ascends and text x less than segment x, or if segment y descends and test x greater than segment x.

Comment: Could you detail your answer with an example? I can't handle it. [This is example link for me](http://i.imgur.com/M33LjWk.png). Black is the main line and we should find the red line is on the left side.

Answer (score -1):

See ST_LineCrossingDirection.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_LineCrossingDirection.html

Comment: As links can change or disappear over time, can you please [edit] your answer to provide the steps required and then reference the link as a source.